# Use of Mindsensors IMU with Labview

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, programming, labview

I thought someone could help me with a the Mindsensors AbsoluteIMU ACG and its use with the Lego Mindstorms NXT. Is it possible to use it with and get data out of it?